# Take screenshot Webbrowser in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser, screenshot, writeablebitmap

I have a code to take screenshot in wp7.

```
int Width = (int)LayoutRoot.RenderSize.Width;
int Height = (int)LayoutRoot.RenderSize.Height;

// Write the map control to a WwriteableBitmap
WriteableBitmap screenshot = new WriteableBitmap(LayoutRoot, new TranslateTransform());

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Save it to a memory stream
    screenshot.SaveJpeg(ms, Width, Height, 0, 100);

    // Take saved memory stream and put it back into an BitmapImage
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
    img.SetSource(ms);

    // Assign to our image control
    ImageFromMap.Width = img.PixelWidth;
    ImageFromMap.Height = img.PixelHeight;
    ImageFromMap.Source = img;

    // Cleanup
    ms.Close();
}
```

In my screen have a webbrowser to display content in internet. when press button Take. i can take a photo of screen but webbrowser area display a white rectangle.

Comment: The WebBrowser is not a silverlight control, but rather a hook to a native control. I don't think this will be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no way to implement a screenshot over WebBrowser. But if you just want a runtime display of screenshot not store to gallery or for tile usage, you can just implement the function by put your WebBrowser control on the screenshot view. Thumbnail of WebBrowser can be implement in WPF way